# Changing a string with a date into a format to get the day of the week

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date

I have an input field that gives me a date in this format "Dec 22, 2015" and I need to get the day for the week out of it. I have tried taking the params and using the `strftime("%A")` however I keep getting nil back.

This is the syntax I used:

```
a = params[:start_date] 
a.strftime("%A")
```

I have seen from other posts I can do:

```
t=Time.new
t.strftime("%A")
```

and that works for `Time.now`. I am not sure why it wouldn't work for my params.

Comment: Request parameters are serialized as strings. You need to convert `params[:start_date]` to a `Date` object before you can use `strftime`. @simonecarletti beat me to the answer

Answer (score 2):

You first need to convert the `String` into a `Time` object.

```
require 'time'

t = Time.parse("Dec 22, 2015")
```

and then format it

```
t.strftime("%A")
 => "Tuesday"
```

Comment: Or you could use `Date#parse` instead of `Time#parse` since the param in the example only has date values.

Comment: @BradleyFarquhar please accept the answer if it solves your problem